# Assigning a Excel Range Value to another Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate (consolidate) a dynamic Range from each sheet from 3 thru 7 to a separate sheet using Ranges so I don't mess with the clipboard. I'm capable to detect the range I want to copy but assigning it to another Range has been problematic.

What is the issue with this line:?

```
Sheets("Consolidar Datos").Range(ConsolidaArea).Value = Sheets(I).Range(NEW_area).Value
```

Both ranges are the exact same size but I'm still getting "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Example of Range to be copied in sheet `#3: B8:O16`

Receiver Range in sheet `"Consolidar Datos": B6:O14`

Example of Range to be copied in sheet `#4: B8:O12`

Receiver Range in sheet `"Consolidar Datos": B15:O19`

Thank you!

```
For I = 3 To 7
    Set sh = Sheets(I)
        With ActiveSheet
            Set area = .Range("C8:O33")
            LastRow = Last(1, area)
            If LastRow <> 0 Then
                CopyRange = "B8:" & "O" & LastRow
                Set NEW_area = .Range(CopyRange)

                If FirstTime = 0 Then
                    CountRows = CountRows - 1 + NEW_area.Rows.Count
                    FirstTime = FirstTime + 1
                Else
                    CountRows = CountRows + NEW_area.Rows.Count
                End If
                ConsolidaCopyRange = StartCell & ":O" & CountRows
                Set ConsolidaArea = .Range(ConsolidaCopyRange)

                Sheets("Consolidar Datos").Range(ConsolidaArea).Value = _   
                     Sheets(I).Range(NEW_area).Value

                StartCell = "B" & CountRows + 1

            End If                
        End With
    Next I
```

Comment: what is `StartCell` for the first iteration?

Comment: StartCell is B6 the first time. Then adds up depending on the selected Range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
For I = 3 To 7
    With Sheets(I)
        Set area = .Range("C8:O33")
        LastRow = Last(1, area)
        If LastRow <> 0 Then
            CopyRange = "B8:" & "O" & LastRow
            Set NEW_area = .Range(CopyRange)

            If FirstTime = 0 Then
                CountRows = CountRows - 1 + NEW_area.Rows.Count
                FirstTime = FirstTime + 1
            Else
                CountRows = CountRows + NEW_area.Rows.Count
            End If
            ConsolidaCopyRange = StartCell & ":O" & CountRows
            Set ConsolidaArea = Sheets("Consolidar Datos").Range(ConsolidaCopyRange)

            ConsolidaArea.Value = NEW_area.Value

            StartCell = "B" & CountRows + 1

        End If
    End With
Next I
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much. But what was the issue with the other line? I've used it before with same results but in this peace of code just it doesn't work.

Comment: Your `ConsolidaArea` and `NEW_area` area ranges was defined both on `ActiveSheet` (and basically from your code `ActiveSheet` isn't equal to `Sheets(I)`). And in the line `Sheets("Consolidar Datos").Range(ConsolidaArea).Value = Sheets(I).Range(NEW_area).Value` you've tried to find ranges from `ActiveSheet` in another sheets, and this was triggered an error.